# Attaching AudioUnit effects to SCNAudioSource nodes in SceneKit

Tags: swift, audiounit

I have successfully created some functions to take an `SNSpeechSynthesizer.startSpeakingString(string, url)` and attach the resulting .aiff file to an `SCNAudioPlayer` through a closure and attach the whole thing to an `SCNNode`.

This runs the audio snippet with given `SCNNode.position(x, y, z)`.

All good but there are no effects associated to the `SCNAudioSource` apart from volume, rate and reverb which itself does nothing.

I would like to add audio unit effects such as delay echo flange etc, but I couldn't find relevant information apart from `AVAudioEngine` and `AVAudioFile` classes which seem to be superclasses for `SCNAudioSource`, for which `AVAudioEngine` contains classes such as `AudioUnitPitc`h and others. However, I can't figure out what the connection between `SCNAudioSource`, `SCNAudioPlayer`, `AVAudioEngine` and `AVAudioFile` are. None refer to the other in sub or super class and any tutorials such as below only speak within `AVFoundation` and not for `SceneKit`.
http://www.jawadrashid.com/swift-tutorial-udacity-7/

Any help to any link somewhere where I can read more about this very much appreciated

Edit: I have found another link that shows the `SCNAudioPlayer` constructor which uses and `AVAudioNode`. Perhaps I can extend this by:

```
class CustomAudioPlayer:SCNAudioPlayer{}
```

Then override the super class init by attaching an AudioUnit to the AudioNode? However, this won't appear in the AudioEngine it seems.

Here's the below link in objective c:

http://developer.xamarin.com/api/constructor/SceneKit.SCNAudioPlayer.SCNAudioPlayer/p/AVFoundation.AVAudioNode/

Edit2: 
I found a reference to an audio unit and did the following but now I have a segment fault

Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

```
code:
    let source = prepareSynth(welcome, url: URL)
        source.volume = 500.0
        source.reverbBlend = 30.0
        source.rate = 0.8
        let clip = SCNAudioPlayer(source: source)
        let mixer = clip.audioNode as AVAudioNode!?
        distortion.loadFactoryPreset(AVAudioUnitDistortionPreset.SpeechRadioTower)
        mixer?.engine?.attachNode(distortion)
        mixer?.engine?.connect(mixer!, to: distortion, format: nil)
        return clip
```

Comment: for best results on stack, make sure your question conforms to [mcve] and make sure you take a look at [ask], welcome to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SO after a lot of researching around to get any of the available AVAudioUnitEffec* effects into a SceneKit scene, I've finally got a solution, tested, tried and played around.

The following sub-class of AVAudioEngine will
1-Instantiate an AVAudioEngine with certain configurations
2-Added a few methods to encapsulate error handling and effects preset loading
3-Have a wire method to put every player and effect nodes into the audio engine graph
4-Create AVAudioPCMBuffer instances with configured frame count, file format as helper method to ease calling these functions from SceneKit

Note: Multi-Channel code was not included as I don't have a surround sound 5.1 system and am already very happy with the HRTF (Head Related Transfer Functions) algorithm exposed from the AVAudioEnvironmentNode class. Beware as this algorithm is the most computer intensive though it is a binaural format.

Possible additions:
1-Adding a reverb zone preset switcher which will require disconnecting the audio engine, rewiring the environment node to a new reverb preset (large hall, small room, etc)
2-Create a RayCast based echo transfer dimension from the SceneKit SCNNode list to add more realistic effects, IE: you are at the central bar of a T junction, an enemy is creaming on the left of the top bar of the junction, the sound traverses the RayCast leaving the enemy and bounces against a wall that is facing you. The AVAudioUnitDelay class has internal functions to change early delay to create the echo effect desired without washing the node with the same ffect wherever you are.

Code here:

```
import Foundation
import SceneKit
import AVFoundation

class AudioLayerEngine:AVAudioEngine{
    var engine:AVAudioEngine!
    var environment:AVAudioEnvironmentNode!
    var outputBuffer:AVAudioPCMBuffer!
    var voicePlayer:AVAudioPlayerNode!
    var multiChannelEnabled:Bool!
    //audio effects
    let delay = AVAudioUnitDelay()
    let distortion = AVAudioUnitDistortion()
    let reverb = AVAudioUnitReverb()

    override init(){
        super.init()
engine = AVAudioEngine()
environment = AVAudioEnvironmentNode()

engine.attachNode(self.environment)
voicePlayer = AVAudioPlayerNode()
engine.attachNode(voicePlayer)
voicePlayer.volume = 1.0
        outputBuffer = loadVoice()
        wireEngine()
        startEngine()
voicePlayer.scheduleBuffer(self.outputBuffer, completionHandler: nil)
voicePlayer.play()
    }

    func startEngine(){
        do{
            try engine.start()
        }catch{
            print("error loading engine")
        }
    }

    func loadVoice()->AVAudioPCMBuffer{
        let URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("art.scnassets/sounds/interface/test", ofType: "aiff")!)
        do{
            let soundFile = try AVAudioFile(forReading: URL, commonFormat: AVAudioCommonFormat.PCMFormatFloat32, interleaved: false)
             outputBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(PCMFormat: soundFile.processingFormat, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(soundFile.length))
            do{
            try soundFile.readIntoBuffer(outputBuffer)
            }catch{
                print("somethign went wrong with loading the buffer into the sound fiel")
            }
            print("returning buffer")
            return outputBuffer
        }catch{
        }
        return outputBuffer
    }

    func wireEngine(){
loadDistortionPreset(AVAudioUnitDistortionPreset.MultiCellphoneConcert)
        engine.attachNode(distortion)
        engine.attachNode(delay)
engine.connect(voicePlayer, to: distortion, format: self.outputBuffer.format)
        engine.connect(distortion, to: delay, format: self.outputBuffer.format)
                engine.connect(delay, to: environment, format: self.outputBuffer.format)
        engine.connect(environment, to: engine.outputNode, format: constructOutputFormatForEnvironment())

    }

    func constructOutputFormatForEnvironment()->AVAudioFormat{
let outputChannelCount = self.engine.outputNode.outputFormatForBus(1).channelCount
let hardwareSampleRate = self.engine.outputNode.outputFormatForBus(1).sampleRate
let environmentOutputConnectionFormat = AVAudioFormat(standardFormatWithSampleRate: hardwareSampleRate, channels: outputChannelCount)
multiChannelEnabled = false
        return environmentOutputConnectionFormat
    }

    func loadDistortionPreset(preset: AVAudioUnitDistortionPreset){
        distortion.loadFactoryPreset(preset)
}

    func createPlayer(node: SCNNode){
        let player = AVAudioPlayerNode()
distortion.loadFactoryPreset(AVAudioUnitDistortionPreset.SpeechCosmicInterference)
engine.attachNode(player)
engine.attachNode(distortion)
engine.connect(player, to: distortion, format: outputBuffer.format)
        engine.connect(distortion, to: environment, format: constructOutputFormatForEnvironment())
let algo = AVAudio3DMixingRenderingAlgorithm.HRTF
        player.renderingAlgorithm = algo
        player.reverbBlend = 0.3
        player.renderingAlgorithm = AVAudio3DMixingRenderingAlgorithm.HRTF
    }

}
```

e

Comment: Thanks for your research and great snippet! How does createPlayer function attach voicePlayer to the input node:SCNNode? The function accepts node:SCNNode as input, but it never uses it.